# Overloading output stream to print entire matrix

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm trying to make << output an entire matrix which I wrote a template for. Not sure why this isn't working, the error is:

```
 error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'matrix<int' and 'int')
 candidate is:
 matrix<Comparable> matrix<Comparable>::operator[](matrix<Comparable>&) [with Comparable = int]|
 no known conversion for argument 1 from 'int' to 'matrix<int>&'|
```

which refers to this line: o << rhs[ i ][ j ].  Am I supposed to overload [ ] as well?

matrix.h:

```
template <typename Comparable>
class matrix
{
    private:
        size_t num_cols_;
        size_t num_rows_;
        Comparable **array_;

    public:
        friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, const matrix<Comparable> & rhs);
        size_t NumRows();
        size_t NumCols();
};
```

matrix.cpp:

```
template <typename Comparable>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, matrix<Comparable> & rhs){
    size_t c = rhs.NumRows();
    size_t d = rhs.NumCols();
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < d; j++){
            o << rhs[i][j];          //error
        }
    }
}

template <typename Comparable>
size_t matrix<Comparable>::NumRows(){
    return num_rows_;
}

template <typename Comparable>
size_t matrix<Comparable>::NumCols(){
    return num_cols_;
}
```

And probably irrelevant but I implemented the matrix like this:

```
array_ = new Comparable*[num_rows_];
for (int i = 0; i < num_rows_; i++){
    array_[i] = new Comparable[num_cols_];
```

Comment: `o << rhs.array_[i][j];`

Comment: Ahh I see, but array_ is a private data member. What should I do instead?

Comment: It gives an error that array_ is private by the way. This works if I make it public, but I need to keep it private

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function signatures don't match:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, const matrix<Comparable> & rhs);
```

is not

```
template <typename Comparable>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& o, matrix<Comparable> & rhs);
```

Notice that one is not a template, and the other is. Also, the first has a const reference argument for `rhs` and the second has just a reference. This mismatch means the function you define isn't `Matrix`'s friend, and so can't access the `private` (or `protected` members of `Matrix`)

What you want is to declare a templated function, and then inform the compiler that a single instantiation (say `ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const matrix<int>& val)` ) is the single function you want to be friends with `matrix<int>`.

To do this, you need to declare that you want only a specific version of the function template, and to do *that* you need to declare the template, and to do *that* you need to declare the templated class.

Ultimately that whole chain of declarations might look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

// forward declare the class so the compiler knows what's up at the
// templated operator<< declaration.
template <typename T>
class Foo; 

// forward declare the templated operator<< so the compiler knows you're
// 'friend'ing a specific instantiation of this template in the
// class definition.
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Foo<T>& value);

template <typename T>
class Foo{
    // declare the instantiation of the operator<< template that shares
    // T with the class template to be a friend:
    // operator<<<> can be separated out into operator<< <>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<<>(std::ostream& out, const Foo<T>& value);
    int bar_;
public:
    Foo(int bar) : bar_{bar}{}
};

// now that you know the contents of `Foo<T>`, define the templated operator<<
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Foo<T>& value){
    return std::cout << "Foo: " << value.bar_;
}

int main(){
    Foo<int>
        a{2},
        b{3};

    std::cout << a << '\n' << b;

}
```

[**Live on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec9da7a9cbdca79a)

You can read further on Template Friends on the [C++ Super-FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends).

Comment: Thanks so much, I've never heard of using <<<> but it actually fixed it. I guess I need to find another C++ book

Comment: It's actually the `operator<<` function name combined with the empty template parameter `<>` that's used to indicate a fully specialized template. You might want to read the Super-FAQ I linked above before picking up another book--it's actually rather helpful for newbies, and answers lots of common questions in a conversational format that's relatively easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a get function to access array_ instead of making it as an public member;